# Задачи которые решаются с помощью asyncio

Tags: python, async-await, asyncio

Я пытаюсь научиться асинхронности. Я решил пару базовых задач с помощью asyncio. Но мне нужно больше. Пожалуйста, приведите список некоторых задач которые решаются с помощью asyncio. Я попытаюсь их решить. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну попробуйте написать простенький IRC-подобный чат. клиент и сервер